# Codeigniter: how can i tell if a model is already loaded?

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, model

Are there native codeigniter functions I can use to tell if a certain model has already been loaded? Can php's `class_exists()` be used to tell if a model has already been loaded?

Comment: Yes you can and it will work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would be tempted to extend the `CI_Loader` core class. (See [extending Core Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html))

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the model with the given name is loaded; false otherwise.
     *
     * @param   string  name for the model
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function is_model_loaded($name) 
    {
        return in_array($name, $this->_ci_models, TRUE);
    }
}
```

You would be checking for a given model with the following:

```
$this->load->is_model_loaded('foobar');
```

[That strategy](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Loader.php#L264) is already being used by the `CI_Loader` class.

This solution supports the model naming feature of CI, where models can have a different name than the model class itself.  The `class_exists` solution wouldn't support that feature, but should work fine if you aren't renaming models.

Note: If you changed your `subclass_prefix` configuration, it might not be `MY_` anymore.

Comment: Similarly in MY_Loader:     function get_ci_models() {
        return $this->_ci_models; 
    } # get_ci_models

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution is to use PHP function **class_exists**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

For example. if you want to check if Post_model has been defined or not.

```
$this->load->model('post_model');

/*

     a lot of code

*/

if ( class_exists("Post_model") ) {
    // yes
}
else {
    // no
}
```

The simplest is the best..

Answer (score 4):

Edited:

You can use the log_message() function.

Put this in your model’s constructor (parent::Model())

```
log_message ("debug", "model is loaded");
```

don’t forget to set the log config to debug mode in the config.php file

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

And set the system/logs directory permission to writable (by default CI will create the log files here)

or set the logs directory in another dir

```
$config['log_path'] = 'another/directory/logs/';
```

CI will then create the log file in the directory. monitor the log files as you like. You can get the debug message to see if your model is already loaded or not in the log files.

Comment: this will only let me know if the file exists, I wanted to know if the first model has been loaded maually in the controller or if has been automatically loaded via autoload

Answer (score 4):

Riffing off what Maxime Morin & Tomexsans have written, this is my solution:

```
<?php 
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader { 
    /**
     * Model Loader
     *
     * Overwrites the default behaviour
     *
     * @param   string  the name of the class
     * @param   string  name for the model
     * @param   bool    database connection
     * @return  void
     */
    function model ($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE) {
        if (is_array($model) || !class_exists($model)) {
            parent::model($model, $name, $db_conn);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This way, you don't ever need to (consciously) check whether a model's loaded or not :)

Comment: I ran into a situation where I was loading classes more than once and it was not throwing any error's but it was using up PHP memory limit and this fixed my issue without needing to modify any other code so thanks a lot!

Comment: AFAICS this is not possible as the parent class already checks if a class has been loaded, so it will not load it twice: if (in_array($name, $this->_ci_models, TRUE))
  {
   return $this;
  }